# How to change alt+tab behavior

Tags: gala

I don't like the behaviour of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut, when changing between windows, how can I change to something like OS X where you see a line of icons rather than changing windows?

[image: Alt + Tab on OSX]

Comment: You  can't simply change it,  I guess you'd need to install some app to take care of the switching between open windows.

Comment: What don't you like about it? Specifically, what should the alternative add or subtract from the experience?

Comment: @LewisGoddard I don't like the fact that I have to look at the bottom of the screen to see a list of the available windows. Also, I am much more effective in selecting a new window when I see its icon with a short text rather than the window itself.

Comment: Is there any update on this? Also would much prefer a OSX behaviour (or even default Ubuntu behaviour) to how eos behaves.

Comment: this is a problem, please add feature to fix. as features go (not counting hang ups and freezes as features, but certainly 'better wine support' as one) it is the most annoying.

Comment: This is a terrible feature. We need a way to revert to OSX/Ubuntu style alt-tab. It's driving everybody I know running eOS crazy.

Comment: I love it actually, compared to my other Ubuntu/Unity laptop :) I'd love to switch off that stupid grouping in Unity :D Thank god Gnome (their next DE) has that covered ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's *theoretically* possible to change this; Gala (the elementary OS window manager) can be extended by plugins. There even *is* a plugin changing the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaviour called [gala-alternative-alt-tab](https://github.com/tom95/gala-alternate-alt-tab).

You can take a look at Tom's (the developer) [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kLVnfWb0o0ay3J1s2VuVoJGvxfL_ZlNk0nQzyOO1AcA/edit#heading=h.2g4v3lnnhdue), which describes the plugins future features and functionality.

**However**, as the GitHub page points out, this is [alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Alpha) software, so there is no package available via repositories and as the last commit was in April, it may not even work at all. Tom has been very busy the past months and this plugin isn't his top priority. So take this information with a grain of salt - It is **not** recommended to install it on your system.

Comment: Damn... 1 min too late :), I've deleted my answer and added some additional information to yours.

Comment: Much ado about nothing: Plank shows precisely that when you cycle windows with Alt-Tab.

Answer (score 5):

Detailed step by step guide of how I accomplished the desired behavior:

Download/clone **the fork**:

`git clone https://github.com/jibbo/gala-elementary-alt-tab-switcher`

Install dependencies:

`sudo apt install cmake build-essential valac libgala-dev libwnck-3-dev libgranite-dev`

Execute the commands:

```
cd gala-elementary-alt-tab-switcher
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
make
sudo make install
```

*Reboot* because just executing `gala --restart` most likely will not suffice

Optional but strongly suggested customization:
`sudo apt install dconf-editor`. Open the dconf-editor and search for *elementary-alt-tab*. Setup the config as following (if you like my settings):

```
active-element-scale 1
all-workspaces off
always-on-primary-monitor off
animate off
caption-visible off (the text is looking rather ugly)
dektop-icon-in-switcher off
desktop-in-switcher off
icon-opacity 255
icon-size 48 (64 is pretty good too)
inactive-element-scale 1
indicator-background-color '#ECEFF4'
indicator-border 4
indicator-round-radius 4
indicator-stroke-width 0
preview-in-switcher off
wrapper-background-color rgba(46, 52, 64, 1)
wrapper-padding 16
wrapper-round-radius 8
wrapper-spacing 8
wrapper-stroke-width 0
```

Tested on *elementary os 5.1.3 Hera* - pleasant performance and no crashes: [image: switcher.png]

UPDATE:
Since elementary 6.1 a similar alt-tab switcher is provided by default. Note: in some cases it can cause lagging upon pressing `Alt + Shift + Tab`, personally I've solved the issue via setting *Keyboard -> Switch Layout -> Both Shift keys together* option.

Comment: Frequently freeze desktop, OS 5.1.7. I tried with default settings, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @daGO's answer , at elementary hera i had to tinker with these settings via dconf-editor built-in search functionality to avoid getting the switcher and the whole DE in a freeze

- desktop-icon-in-switcher off
- desktop-in-switcher off

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to expand on this? Where do you make these changes? I've done some digging online to find this information, but there's nothing from the last 10 years to suggest how one might switch these off ...

Comment: @matigo i suggested using searching rather than an absolute path within dcnof-editor to avoid the inconsistencies between different distributions that maybe be using pantheon DE .