# Classic Alt-Tab switcher animation

Tags: gala

I constantly switch between open windows. The <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> switcher is too slow. Is it possible to integrate a classic-styled <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> switcher? It could be an option in System Settings.

Comment: I agree completely, but this is not the right place for feature requests. Please make a report on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala).

Comment: An answer could be in the form of a third-party package that provides the functionality, so I believe it still has its place here. If OP wants this to be available in the official elementary distribution, then by all means an issue should also be created in Launchpad indeed.

Comment: IMHO it should be closed and flagged as a duplicate of this question: [how to change alt+tab behavior](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/342/how-to-change-alttab-behavior)