# Change alt+tab behaviour

Tags: window-management, gala, window-manager

I strongly dislike the unintuitive behavior of the ALT+TAB switcher.

Applications running:
 1. Files, 
 2. Firefox
 3. Terminal

How to reproduce:
 - Press ALT+TAB twice
 - Press ALT+SHIFT+TAB

Expected application to pop up:
Firefox

Application that pops up:
Terminal

This is happening because ALT+SHIFT+TAB simply replaces the running applications list, and starts from the back, without taking notice of the place where ALT+TAB was focused in the list.

Is there any way to change this behavior, without installing a new window manager?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change alt+tab behavior](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/342/how-to-change-alttab-behavior)